# How do you annotate Django admin's filter_horizontal with associated filed of the M2M field?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How do you annotate Django admin's filter_horizontal?  That is put information about other fields for an entry in the multi select.  For example,

```
class A(models.Model):
    aa = models.CharField()
    bb - models.ManyToManyField('self')

class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ['bb']
```

So bb will show in the multiselect but how do you also show the associated aa field with the bb field?  filter_horizontal will not accept aa as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your field `aa` is simply not registered at the modelAdmin.

**(1)** Either use django's `@admin.register` annotation to register your modelAdmin with your model and all of its legal fields.

```
@admin.register(A)
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        filter_horizontal = ['bb']
```

**(2)** or add the `fieldsets` attr to your modelAdmin where you declare the fields that have to be shown.

```
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('aa', 'bb',)}),
    )
    filter_horizontal = ['bb']
```